# Is it possiblle to change the tag name in kendo dialog?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to rename the tag name from `<kendo-dialog>` to `<sk-dialog>`. Is it possible to change in the runtime which means using some function?

working sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeze7f?file=app/dialogs.component.ts

expected working sample -https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeze7f-slcahh?file=app/dialogs.component.ts

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: thats for my application

Comment: Then wrap the kendo component in your own component and name the selector `sk-dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

you can create the wrapper class of it and import it in your module and use it with the custom name as per your requirement.